# Rで連番のデータフレームを加工して連番で出力する

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Rでデータ前処理中ですが2つほど質問があるので書かせていただきます。

1
data1~data3というデータフレームを読み込み済みで, sum1.csv~sum3.csvというファイルを生成したいと考えています。(実際はもっとパターンが多いため単純に全パターン書くというのは厳しいです。）assignやcsvdataのあたりで読み込みが上手く行かずエラーが出てしまうのでアドバイスをお願い致します。アルゴリズムとしましてはdataにdata1を代入、それを加工しつつcsvdataに加工し出力、dataにdata2を上書きして同じことを繰り返す…という感じです。

```
library(tidyverse)
main <- for(p in 1:3){
assign(data,paste("data", p, sep = ""))
csvdata <- data %>% mutate(hogehoge...)

write_csv(csvdata,paste0("sum",p,".csv"))
}
```

2

```
bind_rows(as.data.frame(a1),as.data.frame(a2),as.data.frame(a3))
```

とデータフレームを縦にくっつけたいのですが、3つのデータフレーム間に空白行がほしいです。
どのように対処すればよいでしょうか？

Comment: 2つの質問がありますが，この2つは近い話ですが別のものだと思いますし，質問タイトルからは1のみに絞るのが適切かと思います。
ですので，2つめの質問はまた別の質問として立てたほうがいいかと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こういう感じのコードではどうでしょうか:

```
# パッケージ読み込み
library(tidyverse)

# テスト用にdata.frame作成
# 以下のコードでdata1-data3というdata.frameができます
data_list <- paste("data", 1:3, sep = "")
for(i in 1:length(data_list)) {
  assign(
    data_list[i],
    data.frame(
      x1 = rnorm(10),
      x2 = rnorm(10)
    )
  )
}

# メインの処理
# data.frameを加工してcsvへの出力
for(i in 1:length(data_list)) {
  get(data_list[i]) %>% 
    mutate(x3 = x1 + x2) %>% 
    write_csv(paste("sum", i, ".csv", sep = ""))
}
```

`assign()`は第一引数に文字列を受け付け，第二引数にアサインする中身を指定します。質問文のコード内で`assign()`を使っている箇所では，第一引数には未定義のオブジェクトであり，また第二引数が単なる文字列となっています。そのためうまく`data`に期待したデータが入らないのかなと思いました。またcsvdataのあたりでのエラーは，(1)`data`にちゃんとデータが格納されていないため，(2)データ加工のコードに問題がある，のどちらかです。

ただ，ここで`assign()`を使ってデータフレームを呼び出すよりも，すでにdata1-data3と連番で存在するようでしたので`get()`で呼び出すコードで書いています。`%>%`を利用されているみたいでしたので，上記コードでも利用しました。

Comment: 最初の`assign`でリストに入れるんですね。
`get`はしらなかったので勉強になりました。解説付きで非常にわかりやすいです。ありがとうございます。